# Problems saving state with SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save the state of a switch in SharedPreferences, but I am having trouble doing this. I have a switch for turning audio on and off.

```
public void audio() {
    audio.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                player= MediaPlayer.create(legoActivity.this, R.raw.sound);
                player.start();

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefss", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("audio", isChecked);
                editor.apply();
                editor.commit();
            }
            ...
        }
        ...       
    });
    ...
}
```

At the end of the activity, in the `oncCreate` method I have:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefss", MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.getBoolean("audio", true);
```

Both code snippets are from the same activity.

Comment: what is the problem? what exception/error are you getting?

Comment: I don't get any exception/error. The state is just not saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only updating your shared preferences when the checkbox is checked, so you are only storing true.
Just remove the if from OnCheckedChanged

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
    player = MediaPlayer.create(legoActivity.this, R.raw.sound);
    player.start();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefss", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("audio", isChecked);
    editor.apply();
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: This does not work. When i enable the switch and switch activity, the switch is not saved.

Comment: can you provide some context about how are using prefs.getBoolean("audio", true) ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried recovering your boolean on your onCreate(), then setting the switch after that?

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefss", MODE_PRIVATE);
 audio.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean("audio", true));
```